# Order item quantity increased instead of updated

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, configurable-product

When I change the quantity of a cart item from the product "configure" page (.../checkout/cart/configure/id/...), the order item quantity is increased with the quantity, instead of updated.

i.e. if I hit the Edit link of a product from my cart, set the quantity to 2 and hit the "Update Cart" button, I end up with a quantity of 3 for this product, instead of 2.

Any helper please ?

Comment: This is actually default behaviour for Magento since the quantity can be changed inside the cart directly. I am not sure if there is an easy way to konfigure the setting to work differently.

Comment: I do have a bug in my installation, because if I change an option of a configurable product and hit "Update Cart", I end up with a new order item in the cart view. It should clearly update the initial order item's option instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was coming from my catalog/product/view.phtml template override line 42.

The form's action method was set to always add to cart. I fixed it by replacing the line

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

with

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```